# .NET API Controller retornando status code 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho um controller que independente do que eu mande ele retorna erro 400 antes mesmo de conseguir entrar na primeira linha (acredito que esteja relacionado a serialização).

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertAsync([FromBody]Person person)
{
    var response = await _personWebService.InsertAsync(person);

    if (response.HasErrors)
        return BadRequest(response.ToStringErrors());

    return CreatedAtAction("teste", "foi");
}
```

O modelo pedido no body é o seguinte (mesmo especificando com notações como [JsonIgnore] o erro persiste):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Collection<Core.Models.Character> Characters { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Core.Models.Person(Person source)
    {
        return new Core.Models.Person()
        {
            Id = source.Id,
            Name = source.Name,
            Characters = source.Characters
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator Person(Core.Models.Person source)
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            Id = source.Id,
            Name = source.Name,
            Characters = source.Characters
        };
    }
}
```

Abaixo está a requisição feita:

```
{
  "name": "nome random",
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "nome random 2",
      "gender": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

E sempre retorna o erro:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-f2e3749f4eef0f324418a6c3de6698f2-ddbf0cfde678f99c-00",
  "errors": {
    "person": [
      "The person field is required."
    ],
    "$.characters[0].gender": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Char. Path: $.characters[0].gender | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 24."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Consegue adicionar o código do método _personWebService.InsertAsync(person)? 2. O json de erro indica um problema no parametro person que você está passando para o método InsertAsync. Já tentou colocar um breakpoint na primeira linha do seu método e investigar o objeto person?

Comment: Mesmo com o breakpoint ele não para como se estivesse o "ignorando", até pensei que fosse problema com meu vs e reinstalei. @TallesSantana

Comment: Adiciona o código do método InserAsync da classe PersonWebService?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia gadelha, tudo bem?

O erro realmente é na serialização e são dois erros conforme do conforme a mensagem que você está recebendo

```
"errors": {
"person": [
  "The person field is required."
],
"$.characters[0].gender": [
  "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Char. Path: $.characters[0].gender | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 24."
]
```

}

O Primeiro erro: "The person field is required." pode ser pelos implicit operators que você tem na classes. Geralmente classes que vão servir como objetos de request eu tento manter o mais simples possível.

O Segundo erro: ""$.characters[0].gender": [
"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Char. Path: $.characters[0].gender | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 24."
]" provavelmente é o tipo de dado que você está esperando com o tipo de dado que está chegando, algum erro na conversão de string para char... Tente deixar no seu objeto como string.